# Query syntax in URL when using Spring and @QuerydslPredicate

Tags: spring, jpa, querydsl

How can I write the HTTP request URL in order to get a query similar to:

```
select *
from incidents i,
     jira_issues ji
where i.incident_id = ji.incident_id
  and ji.external_jira_issue_id = 'ABC-123'
  and ji.jira_server_id = '1'
```

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity(name = "incidents")
public class IncidentEntity {
  @OneToMany(
      mappedBy = "incident",
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL
  )
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private List<JiraIssueEntity> jiraIssues;
...
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "jira_issues")
public class JiraIssueEntity {

  @EmbeddedId
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private JiraIssueId id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "incident_id")
  @ToString.Exclude
  private IncidentEntity incident;
...
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class JiraIssueId implements Serializable {

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private String externalJiraIssueId;
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private String jiraServerId;
}
```

This is my API method signature:

```
  @GetMapping("")
  public Page<Incident> listIncidents(
      @QuerydslPredicate(root = IncidentEntity.class) Predicate predicate
  );
```

I know that I can send something like:

```
/incidents/?jiraIssues.id.externalJiraIssueId=ABC-123&jiraIssues.id.jiraServerId=1"
```

This translates to the following query:

```
select *
from incidents incidenten0_
where (exists(select 1
              from jira_issues jiraissues1_
              where incidenten0_.incident_id = jiraissues1_.incident_id
                and (lower(jiraissues1_.external_jira_issue_id) like ? escape '!')))
  and (exists(select 1
              from jira_issues jiraissues2_
              where incidenten0_.incident_id = jiraissues2_.incident_id
                and (lower(jiraissues2_.jira_server_id) like ? escape '!')))
```

which is not so good.

I don't know how to:

1. Do equals and not contains (rows with externalJiraIssueId=ABC-1234 will return as well but I don't want that).
2. Check that same JiraIssue has externalJiraIssueId=ABC-123 and jiraIssues.id.jiraServerId=1 and not different JiraIssues that each matches one (something like jiraIssues.id=(ABC-123, 1)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

regarding the first problem you can make your 'repository' interface extend QuerydslPredicateExecutor and QuerydslBinderCustomizer
then you can override the 'customize' method with something like this:

```
    @Override
      default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, @NotNull QIncidentEntity root) 
      {
         bindings.bind(String.class)
            .first((SingleValueBinding<StringPath, String>) 
                StringExpression::equalsIgnoreCase);
      }
```

this will make the query check for equals (ignoring the case) and not contains.